# When I SSH into my raspberry with a specific user, it always logs in as root instead of that user

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, ssh, raspberry-pi

Whenever I log in through **SSH**, or even when I log in on the raspberry's terminal, it always logs in as root, instead of that user.

I have two users, the one I work with and the default "pi" user, which I never use. If I try to log in as pi, it works fine, but if I log in with the other user, it logs in as root instead.

The command prompt says `root@<ipaddress>:~#` BUT if I do `printenv` it displays the correct env for the user that I want to log in with.

I can't figure out what I did, so if you have any ideas, please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

The user I was using had the same UID as root, 0, therefore the console displays the logged in user as root, even though you are logged in as another user!

This was a mistake on my part, and I know that you should never ever give another user the same UID as root!

Answer (score 0):

Type `who am i` from command propt. possibly the message is not correct
If it says not root, but the correct user, then the problem is in setting your PS1 environment variable. Set it to correct value in .bash_profile

Comment: Doing that displayed the correct user, not root. How do I set the PS1 environment variable? There is no .bash_profile I only have .profile under the user's home directory

Comment: At least there is no problem with log in :) You can type `PS1="\u@\h:"` from command promt to set it correctly. If you want it on permanent basis you should edit your .bashrc if you have one. There is an article on this topic: [http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html]

Comment: Ok, so, setting PS1 like you told me still shows "root" for the username! Even though I'm not logged in as root...

Comment: If you create file - who is the owner? `touch tmp.test && ls -la tmp.test`